# Count Common UserIDs using MySQL between Month X and Month X+1, Month X+2, etc

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following table named Transactions where the timestamp column is in the Unix timestamp format with the minimum timestamp value being January 2008 and the maximum timestamp value is December 2008 (I'm only concerned with months for this problem):

```
+---------+--------+----------+------------+
| orderID | userID | cityName | timestamp  |
+---------+--------+----------+------------+
|       1 |      1 | city1    | 1199590481 |
|       2 |      2 | city2    | 1199590481 |
|       3 |      1 | city1    | 1199590481 |
|       4 |      2 | city2    | 1199590481 |
|       5 |      1 | city1    | 1202268881 |
|       6 |      2 | city2    | 1202268881 |
|       7 |      1 | city1    | 1202268881 |
|       8 |      2 | city2    | 1202268881 |
|       9 |      1 | city1    | 1199590481 |
|      10 |      2 | city2    | 1202268881 |
|      11 |      1 | city1    | 1205549051 |
|      12 |      2 | city2    | 1208227451 |
|      13 |      1 | city1    | 1210819451 |
|      14 |      2 | city2    | 1213497851 |
|      15 |      1 | city1    | 1216089851 |
|      16 |      2 | city1    | 1218768251 |
|      17 |      1 | city2    | 1221446651 |
|      18 |      2 | city2    | 1224038651 |
|      19 |      1 | city1    | 1226717051 |
|      20 |      2 | city2    | 1229309051 |
+---------+--------+----------+------------+
20 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Here's the code to generate the Transactions table I have:

```
CREATE TABLE Transactions (orderID SMALLINT UNSIGNED,userID SMALLINT UNSIGNED,cityName VARCHAR(40),timestamp int(11),constraint pk_Transactions PRIMARY KEY (orderID));

INSERT INTO Transactions (orderID,userID,cityName,timestamp) VALUES(1,1,'city1',1199590481),(2,2,'city2',1199590481),(3,1,'city1',1199590481),(4,2,'city2',1199590481),(5,1,'city1',1202268881),(6,2,'city2',1202268881),(7,1,'city1',1202268881),(8,2,'city2',1202268881),(9,1,'city1',1200375000),(10,2,'city2',1203053400),(11,1,'city1',1205559000),(12,2,'city2',1208237400),(13,1,'city1',1210829400),(14,2,'city2',1213507800),(15,1,'city1',1216099800),(16,2,'city1',1218778200),(17,1,'city2',1221456600),         (18,2,'city2',1224048600),(19,1,'city1',1226727000),(20,2,'city2',1229319000);
```

My task is to count the common userIDs between each month X and month X+1, month X+2 etc, as in the first two columns of the table posted below (with the same format) to see how users are retained between each month of the year and every other later month.

Basically, If the user has ordered during the months written in the row values for the column Month 1 and column Month 2 in the below table, then that user is included in the count. If he hasn't ordered in both Month 1 and Month 2, then the user isn't counted.

The Month 1 and Month 2 columns in the table below should stay as they are, with only the counts being corrected. The number of rows in the table below should stay the same as well, this means including 0 count values in cases where no user has ordered in both the respective Month 1 and Month 2 row values.

In my Transactions table I only have two users, so the count should never be above 2 in any row which isn't the case in the table below that my query generated:

```
+---------+---------+------------------------+
| Month 1 | Month 2 | Transacting user count |
+---------+---------+------------------------+
| 200801  | 200802  |                     25 |
| 200801  | 200803  |                      5 |
| 200801  | 200804  |                      5 |
| 200801  | 200805  |                      5 |
| 200801  | 200806  |                      5 |
| 200801  | 200807  |                      5 |
| 200801  | 200808  |                      5 |
| 200801  | 200809  |                      5 |
| 200801  | 200810  |                      5 |
| 200801  | 200811  |                      5 |
| 200801  | 200812  |                      5 |
| 200802  | 200803  |                      5 |
| 200802  | 200804  |                      5 |
| 200802  | 200805  |                      5 |
| 200802  | 200806  |                      5 |
| 200802  | 200807  |                      5 |
| 200802  | 200808  |                      5 |
| 200802  | 200809  |                      5 |
| 200802  | 200810  |                      5 |
| 200802  | 200811  |                      5 |
| 200802  | 200812  |                      5 |
| 200803  | 200804  |                      1 |
| 200803  | 200805  |                      1 |
| 200803  | 200806  |                      1 |
| 200803  | 200807  |                      1 |
| 200803  | 200808  |                      1 |
| 200803  | 200809  |                      1 |
| 200803  | 200810  |                      1 |
| 200803  | 200811  |                      1 |
| 200803  | 200812  |                      1 |
| 200804  | 200805  |                      1 |
| 200804  | 200806  |                      1 |
| 200804  | 200807  |                      1 |
| 200804  | 200808  |                      1 |
| 200804  | 200809  |                      1 |
| 200804  | 200810  |                      1 |
| 200804  | 200811  |                      1 |
| 200804  | 200812  |                      1 |
| 200805  | 200806  |                      1 |
| 200805  | 200807  |                      1 |
| 200805  | 200808  |                      1 |
| 200805  | 200809  |                      1 |
| 200805  | 200810  |                      1 |
| 200805  | 200811  |                      1 |
| 200805  | 200812  |                      1 |
| 200806  | 200807  |                      1 |
| 200806  | 200808  |                      1 |
| 200806  | 200809  |                      1 |
| 200806  | 200810  |                      1 |
| 200806  | 200811  |                      1 |
| 200806  | 200812  |                      1 |
| 200807  | 200808  |                      1 |
| 200807  | 200809  |                      1 |
| 200807  | 200810  |                      1 |
| 200807  | 200811  |                      1 |
| 200807  | 200812  |                      1 |
| 200808  | 200809  |                      1 |
| 200808  | 200810  |                      1 |
| 200808  | 200811  |                      1 |
| 200808  | 200812  |                      1 |
| 200809  | 200810  |                      1 |
| 200809  | 200811  |                      1 |
| 200809  | 200812  |                      1 |
| 200810  | 200811  |                      1 |
| 200810  | 200812  |                      1 |
| 200811  | 200812  |                      1 |
+---------+---------+------------------------+
66 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, the Transacting user count values don't make any sense at all, especially given that I have only 2 userIDs in my Transactions table.

I'd really appreciate some help in writing a query for this. Here is the query I used to unsuccessfully generate the table above:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FROM_UNIXTIME(T1.timestamp, "%Y%m") 'Month 1',
FROM_UNIXTIME(T2.timestamp, "%Y%m") 'Month 2', 
count(*) 'Transacting user count'
FROM Transactions T1
JOIN Transactions T2
ON FROM_UNIXTIME(T1.timestamp, "%Y%m") < FROM_UNIXTIME(T2.timestamp, "%Y%m")
JOIN (
  SELECT count(*) FROM(
    SELECT userID
    FROM Transactions T1
    WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp, "%Y%m") = (FROM_UNIXTIME(T1.timestamp, "%Y%m"))
    INTERSECT
    SELECT userID
    FROM Transactions T2
    WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp, "%Y%m") = (FROM_UNIXTIME(T2.timestamp, "%Y%m"))
    ) union_table
  ) count_orders
GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(T1.timestamp, "%Y%m"), FROM_UNIXTIME(T2.timestamp, "%Y%m")
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

If anything is unclear then please let me know and I'll try my best to clarify.

EDIT: I managed to edit NickW's second query to get the result I want. Here's the query I used based on his second answer:

```
With date_combos as (
  SELECT DISTINCT FROM_UNIXTIME(T1.timestamp, "%Y%m") YEAR_MONTH1,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(T2.timestamp, "%Y%m") YEAR_MONTH2 
  FROM Transactions T1
  JOIN Transactions T2
  ON FROM_UNIXTIME(T1.timestamp, "%Y%m") < FROM_UNIXTIME(T2.timestamp, "%Y%m")
  GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(T1.timestamp, "%Y%m"), FROM_UNIXTIME(T2.timestamp, "%Y%m")
  ORDER BY 1, 2
),
txn_month as (
  SELECT DISTINCT userID, FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp, "%Y%m") order_month
  FROM Transactions
),
month_counts as (
  SELECT dc.YEAR_MONTH1, dc.YEAR_MONTH2 ,tm1.userId, tm1.order_month
  FROM date_combos dc
  INNER JOIN txn_month tm1 on dc.year_month1 = tm1.order_month
  INNER JOIN txn_month tm2 on dc.year_month2 = tm2.order_month
    AND tm1.userId = tm2.userId
)
SELECT dc.year_month1, dc.year_month2, count(mc.userId)
FROM date_combos dc
LEFT OUTER JOIN month_counts mc on dc.year_month1 = mc.year_month1
    AND dc.year_month2 = mc.year_month2
GROUP BY dc.year_month1, dc.year_month2
ORDER BY dc.year_month1, dc.year_month2;
```

And here's the correct result I got:

```
+-------------+-------------+------------------+
| year_month1 | year_month2 | count(mc.userId) |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+
| 200801      | 200802      |                2 |
| 200801      | 200803      |                1 |
| 200801      | 200804      |                1 |
| 200801      | 200805      |                1 |
| 200801      | 200806      |                1 |
| 200801      | 200807      |                1 |
| 200801      | 200808      |                1 |
| 200801      | 200809      |                1 |
| 200801      | 200810      |                1 |
| 200801      | 200811      |                1 |
| 200801      | 200812      |                1 |
| 200802      | 200803      |                1 |
| 200802      | 200804      |                1 |
| 200802      | 200805      |                1 |
| 200802      | 200806      |                1 |
| 200802      | 200807      |                1 |
| 200802      | 200808      |                1 |
| 200802      | 200809      |                1 |
| 200802      | 200810      |                1 |
| 200802      | 200811      |                1 |
| 200802      | 200812      |                1 |
| 200803      | 200804      |                0 |
| 200803      | 200805      |                1 |
| 200803      | 200806      |                0 |
| 200803      | 200807      |                1 |
| 200803      | 200808      |                0 |
| 200803      | 200809      |                1 |
| 200803      | 200810      |                0 |
| 200803      | 200811      |                1 |
| 200803      | 200812      |                0 |
| 200804      | 200805      |                0 |
| 200804      | 200806      |                1 |
| 200804      | 200807      |                0 |
| 200804      | 200808      |                1 |
| 200804      | 200809      |                0 |
| 200804      | 200810      |                1 |
| 200804      | 200811      |                0 |
| 200804      | 200812      |                1 |
| 200805      | 200806      |                0 |
| 200805      | 200807      |                1 |
| 200805      | 200808      |                0 |
| 200805      | 200809      |                1 |
| 200805      | 200810      |                0 |
| 200805      | 200811      |                1 |
| 200805      | 200812      |                0 |
| 200806      | 200807      |                0 |
| 200806      | 200808      |                1 |
| 200806      | 200809      |                0 |
| 200806      | 200810      |                1 |
| 200806      | 200811      |                0 |
| 200806      | 200812      |                1 |
| 200807      | 200808      |                0 |
| 200807      | 200809      |                1 |
| 200807      | 200810      |                0 |
| 200807      | 200811      |                1 |
| 200807      | 200812      |                0 |
| 200808      | 200809      |                0 |
| 200808      | 200810      |                1 |
| 200808      | 200811      |                0 |
| 200808      | 200812      |                1 |
| 200809      | 200810      |                0 |
| 200809      | 200811      |                1 |
| 200809      | 200812      |                0 |
| 200810      | 200811      |                0 |
| 200810      | 200812      |                1 |
| 200811      | 200812      |                0 |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+
66 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thanks for the help NickW and ValNik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This SQL should give you what you want. If it doesn't please update your question with the result you are expecting.

```
with DATA1 as (
  SELECT userid
  , FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp, "%Y%m")  YEAR_MONTH1
  , date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) + interval 1 month, "%Y%m")  YEAR_MONTH2
  FROM Transactions
)
SELECT A.YEAR_MONTH1, A.YEAR_MONTH2, COUNT(A.USERID)
FROM DATA1 A
INNER JOIN DATA1 B ON A.USERID = B.USERID AND A.YEAR_MONTH2 = B.YEAR_MONTH2
GROUP BY A.YEAR_MONTH1, A.YEAR_MONTH2
ORDER BY A.YEAR_MONTH1, A.YEAR_MONTH2
```

**SECOND ANSWER**

This may give you what you want. If not, please update the table in your question to show the actual values you are expecting.

```
with dates1 as (
  select distinct FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp, "%Y%m") month_val
  FROM Transactions
),
date_combos as (
  select a.month_val as YEAR_MONTH1
  , b.month_val as YEAR_MONTH2
  from dates1 a
  cross join dates1 b
  where  a.month_val <  b.month_val

),
txn_month as (
  select distinct userID, FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp, "%Y%m") order_month
  from Transactions
),
usr_month1 as (
  select dc.YEAR_MONTH1, dc.YEAR_MONTH2
  ,tm1.userId, tm1.order_month
  from date_combos dc
  inner join txn_month tm1 on dc.year_month1 = tm1.order_month
  inner join txn_month tm2 on dc.year_month2 = tm2.order_month
    and tm1.userId = tm2.userId
)
select um1.year_month1, year_month2, count(um1.userId)
from usr_month1 um1
group by  um1.year_month1, year_month2
order by  um1.year_month1, year_month2
;
```

Comment: This isn't what I'm trying to do unfortunately. Please see the second table I posted. I want the columns Month 1 and Month 2 to be identical to what I have, just with the correct counts.

The column Month 2 should be every month that comes after Month 1. For example, if Month 1 is 5 then Month 2 is 6-12, with the Month 1 value repeating itself for the entire Month 2 range.

If the user has ordered in BOTH Month 1 AND Month 2 then the user is included in the count, otherwise they aren't included. I've edited my question like you asked to try and make it more clear.

Comment: So is that table what you want to achieve? If so, the statement " and the numbers don't make any sense at all as you can see" is confusing as it implies that the numbers in the table don't make sense and so is not what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes I want that same table I generated, with the 1st and 2nd columns to stay as they are, only with the correct count values in the 3rd column. I edited my statement to make it less confusing. By "numbers" I meant the count values in the 3rd column don't make sense. I want only the users who ordered in both Month 1 and Month 2 to be counted. There's only 2 users in my original Transactions table so the count values in the third column should never be more than 2 in any case. Sorry for any confusion. I've edited my question so it should be clearer now.

Comment: Your new answer is almost perfect. The counts in the 3rd column are correct. Would it just be possible to include all the possible permutations of the months like I did in my query, which produced 66 rows? Yours produces only  41 rows. This would mean including month permutations where the count value is 0.

Comment: I fiddled with your second query a bit and got it working the way I intended. Thanks a lot. I'll include how I changed your query to get it working the way I want and the corresponding result I got in my OP edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try also this

```
with tranmon as(
  SELECT userid
      ,FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp, "%Y%m") mon
  FROM Transactions T1
  GROUP BY userid, FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp, "%Y%m")
)
select from_mon,to_mon
   ,case when to_mon is null then 0 else count(*) end usersqty
from(
   select t1.userid,t1.mon from_mon,t2.mon to_mon
   from tranmon t1
   left join tranmon t2
      on t2.userid=t1.userid and t2.mon>t1.mon
   group by t1.userid,t1.mon,t2.mon
) t
group by from_mon,to_mon;
```

Result (part)

| from_mon | to_mon | usersqty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 200801 | 200802 | 2 |
| 200801 | 200803 | 1 |
| 200801 | 200805 | 1 |
| 200801 | 200807 | 1 |
| 200801 | 200809 | 1 |
| 200801 | 200811 | 1 |
| 200801 | 200804 | 1 |
| 200801 | 200806 | 1 |
| 200801 | 200808 | 1 |
| 200801 | 200810 | 1 |
| 200801 | 200812 | 1 |
| 200802 | 200803 | 1 |
| 200802 | 200805 | 1 |
| 200802 | 200807 | 1 |

...
Updated2:
New query example. All month from first to last month (YYYYMM) of table Transactions included, regardless of whether the user had orders this month

```
with recursive allmonths as(
  select FROM_UNIXTIME(min(timestamp), "%Y%m") mn
      ,FROM_UNIXTIME(max(timestamp), "%Y%m") maxmn
  from Transactions
  union all
  select mn+1, maxmn from allmonths where mn<maxmn
)
,allmontomon as(
  select t1.mn from_mon,t2.mn to_mon
  from allmonths t1
  left join allmonths t2 on t2.mn>t1.mn
)
,tranmon as(
  SELECT userid
      ,FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp, "%Y%m") mon
  FROM Transactions T1
  GROUP BY userid, FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp, "%Y%m")
)
,um as(
select from_mon,to_mon
  ,case when to_mon is null then 0 else count(*) end usersqty
  ,group_concat(cast(t.userid as char)) lst
from(
   select t1.userid,t1.mon from_mon,t2.mon to_mon
   from tranmon t1
   left join tranmon t2
      on t2.userid=t1.userid and t2.mon>t1.mon
   group by t1.userid,t1.mon,t2.mon
) t
  group by from_mon,to_mon
)
select from_mon,to_mon
   ,case when usersqty is null then 0 else usersqty end usersqty
from allmontomon c
left join um on c.from_mon=um.from_mon and c.to_mon=um.to_mon
order by c.from_mon,c.to_mon
```

[Example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Xfa_rKuC)

Comment: The counts are correct, but not all the possible combinations of months are included. The values in Month 2 should be every possible value that comes after Month 1. For example, if Month 1 is 3, then Month 2 is every value from 4-12, with the 3 value in Month 1 repeating itself for the entire Month 2 range, just like in the first two columns of the second table I posted. Also, the last two values in the Month 2 column are null for some reason when I run this query.

Comment: The question remains - if there were no orders in some month, what output data are expected? Test data is lean - a lot of questions about the desired result.

Comment: The number of rows should stay the same as in the table that my query generated. This means that in cases where there were no common userID orders in the respective months, the count should be 0 and should be included in the table. It is strictly only the third column's values alone that should be changed to reflect the correct count values for each row.

Comment: Your edit isn't what I'm looking for unfortunately. Running this query gives me 5 columns. I want my query to have the exact same format as table I generated in the query in my OP, but with the correct counts for each month (including 0 counts).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to edit NickW's second query to get the result I want. Here's the query I used based on his second answer:

```
With date_combos as (
  SELECT DISTINCT FROM_UNIXTIME(T1.timestamp, "%Y%m") YEAR_MONTH1,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(T2.timestamp, "%Y%m") YEAR_MONTH2 
  FROM Transactions T1
  JOIN Transactions T2
  ON FROM_UNIXTIME(T1.timestamp, "%Y%m") < FROM_UNIXTIME(T2.timestamp, "%Y%m")
  GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(T1.timestamp, "%Y%m"), FROM_UNIXTIME(T2.timestamp, "%Y%m")
  ORDER BY 1, 2
),
txn_month as (
  SELECT DISTINCT userID, FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp, "%Y%m") order_month
  FROM Transactions
),
month_counts as (
  SELECT dc.YEAR_MONTH1, dc.YEAR_MONTH2 ,tm1.userId, tm1.order_month
  FROM date_combos dc
  INNER JOIN txn_month tm1 on dc.year_month1 = tm1.order_month
  INNER JOIN txn_month tm2 on dc.year_month2 = tm2.order_month
    AND tm1.userId = tm2.userId
)
SELECT dc.year_month1, dc.year_month2, count(mc.userId)
FROM date_combos dc
LEFT OUTER JOIN month_counts mc on dc.year_month1 = mc.year_month1
    AND dc.year_month2 = mc.year_month2
GROUP BY dc.year_month1, dc.year_month2
ORDER BY dc.year_month1, dc.year_month2;
```

And here's the correct result I got:

```
+-------------+-------------+------------------+
| year_month1 | year_month2 | count(mc.userId) |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+
| 200801      | 200802      |                2 |
| 200801      | 200803      |                1 |
| 200801      | 200804      |                1 |
| 200801      | 200805      |                1 |
| 200801      | 200806      |                1 |
| 200801      | 200807      |                1 |
| 200801      | 200808      |                1 |
| 200801      | 200809      |                1 |
| 200801      | 200810      |                1 |
| 200801      | 200811      |                1 |
| 200801      | 200812      |                1 |
| 200802      | 200803      |                1 |
| 200802      | 200804      |                1 |
| 200802      | 200805      |                1 |
| 200802      | 200806      |                1 |
| 200802      | 200807      |                1 |
| 200802      | 200808      |                1 |
| 200802      | 200809      |                1 |
| 200802      | 200810      |                1 |
| 200802      | 200811      |                1 |
| 200802      | 200812      |                1 |
| 200803      | 200804      |                0 |
| 200803      | 200805      |                1 |
| 200803      | 200806      |                0 |
| 200803      | 200807      |                1 |
| 200803      | 200808      |                0 |
| 200803      | 200809      |                1 |
| 200803      | 200810      |                0 |
| 200803      | 200811      |                1 |
| 200803      | 200812      |                0 |
| 200804      | 200805      |                0 |
| 200804      | 200806      |                1 |
| 200804      | 200807      |                0 |
| 200804      | 200808      |                1 |
| 200804      | 200809      |                0 |
| 200804      | 200810      |                1 |
| 200804      | 200811      |                0 |
| 200804      | 200812      |                1 |
| 200805      | 200806      |                0 |
| 200805      | 200807      |                1 |
| 200805      | 200808      |                0 |
| 200805      | 200809      |                1 |
| 200805      | 200810      |                0 |
| 200805      | 200811      |                1 |
| 200805      | 200812      |                0 |
| 200806      | 200807      |                0 |
| 200806      | 200808      |                1 |
| 200806      | 200809      |                0 |
| 200806      | 200810      |                1 |
| 200806      | 200811      |                0 |
| 200806      | 200812      |                1 |
| 200807      | 200808      |                0 |
| 200807      | 200809      |                1 |
| 200807      | 200810      |                0 |
| 200807      | 200811      |                1 |
| 200807      | 200812      |                0 |
| 200808      | 200809      |                0 |
| 200808      | 200810      |                1 |
| 200808      | 200811      |                0 |
| 200808      | 200812      |                1 |
| 200809      | 200810      |                0 |
| 200809      | 200811      |                1 |
| 200809      | 200812      |                0 |
| 200810      | 200811      |                0 |
| 200810      | 200812      |                1 |
| 200811      | 200812      |                0 |
+-------------+-------------+------------------+
66 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thanks for the help NickW and ValNik.

Comment: Pls, check. this may be an unlikely option for you, however, if you change (delete row   (12,2,'city2',1208237400))  test data, the data of the 4th month will not be included in the output result.